# Is there a way to stop rust-analyzer from dimming "inactive" code?

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I am currently making an embedded system.
For that I have 2 different panic handlers based on whether it is run normally or as a test.
`#[cfg(test)]`
for the test panic handler and
`#[cfg(not(test))]`
for the normal panic handler.

rust-analyzer says: code is inactive due to #[cfg] directives: test is enabled

and grays out the function.
Test is never explicitly set so I cant just change it and I don't want to disable the graying out inactive code across the workspace.

Is there a way to either disable rust-analyzer checking the test cfg, or to disable the gray out just for this function

I tried finding infos about the test flag but I couldn't find any, i'm using VS Code if it is important

Comment: I would also be curious to find out how to do this with arbitrary features in CLion/Intellij.

Comment: If you will disable the inactive cfgs, you will get two functions with the same name, which is an error. Do you want that?

Comment: no but I'd rather have #[cfg(test)] inactive by default instead of #[cfg(not(test))]

Comment: Related: [Code is inactive hint on `#[cfg(not(test))]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/7529) and the linked issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VSCode's workspaces settings, set the following:

```rust
"rust-analyzer.cargo.extraEnv": {
  "RUSTFLAGS": "--cfg rust_analyzer"
}
```

This will enable the `#[cfg(rust_analyzer)]` for rust-analyzer metadata inspection.

Then, replace `#[cfg(not(test))]` with `#[cfg(any(not(test), rust_analyzer))]`, and `#[cfg(test)]` with `#[cfg(all(test, not(rust_analyzer)))]`. This will disable and enable the functions for testing as usual, but when running in rust-analyzer, only the no-test function will be enabled.

**Important:** this will only work if you don't need to set special `RUSTFLAGS` for your workspace.

Comment: Thank you, do you have the link to the docs, so I can read up on what exactly this does?

Comment: @lv4 https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual for `extraEnv`, https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#--cfg-configure-the-compilation-environment for the `--cfg`, and the rest is just normal Rust cfg.